# Read an element of an array whilst containing various data

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently seeking for a bit of help with the use of arrays. Quite a newbie on the Java language, so excuse the poor etiquette towards the programming format and I forwardly thank for any answers provided.

My current quarrel with the Array is how to fetch data from any array element. Currently I use the method **System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listarray))** but the problem with this method is that it's not necessarily User friendly and it can't be formatted (to my little knowledge). So I'd like to ask help on how to fetch data from an element of an array and put it in a way so its readable by any given user.

Here is the code I'm utilizing:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class principal { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Array Example");
    String[] listarray = new String[10];
    int i = 0;
    byte op;        
    do {
    System.out.println("Select your option:");
    System.out.println("1-Add");
    System.out.println("2-Check");
    System.out.println("3-Change");
    op = input.nextByte();
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("First String:");
            String a1 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Second String:");
            String a2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Third String:");
            String a3 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("(" + (i + 1) + "/10)");
            listarray[i] = a1 + a2 + a3;
            i++;
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listarray));
            break;
        }
    }while(op != 9);

}
}
```

While the code does work, I'd like to know how to format the data, and from a single element, not every element. Or *even* if I can. Thanks and I appreciate the time spent reading this question.

Comment: `listarray[position]` is simply how you can access individual objects of list.

Comment: To clarify your question, when you say fetch data from an array element do you mean the element at a given position in the array? For instance, the 5th element?

Comment: If you want a fine tuned output, you will have to do it in another way. Arrays.toString() just calls toString of each element in the array.

Comment: Yes, I mean accessing a given's element (say, the 5th) with its data. My problem is that I have varied data in it and I would like just that specific element with all its data formatted. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to traverse the Array that is how you can do it:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(listArray[i]);
}
```

or

```
 for (String s : listArray) {
    System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seemed to do the trick. I appreciate your answer on this, it was killing me and the way it seemed so simple just made me squirm like I was an idiot. Thank you, once again, it saved my skin.

Comment: Good it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

You have two questions:

1. How do you *reference* an array element?
2. How do you format output?

When you declare an array like

```
String[10] names;
```

You have an array that can hold 10 strings, numbered 0 to 9. To reference the fifth element (remembering that array indices start at 0), you would use

```
names[4]
```

You can do various things with a reference. If you put it on the right side of an equals sign, then you are assigning the value at that element to something else.

```
currentName = names[4];
```

If you put it on the left side, you are assigning something to that element.

```
names[4] = "Michael";
```

And if you put it in a println statement, it will output the value to wherever the println statement is putting things at that time, usually the console:

```
System.out.println(names[4]);
```

So much for references. And, incidentally, that's what it is called -- you are referencing the 5th element of the array, or you are referencing the indicated element of the array. You can also put the number in a variable:

```
var i = 4;
System.out.println[i];
```

Note that most of these uses of the reference assume there is something IN that element of the array. Until something is assigned there, the element is a null.

To format, I recommend looking (carefully) into the Format / Formatter classes and choosing some simple things to do what you want. As an example, you could have:

```
String formatString = "The name is currently %s.";
String outputString = String.format(formatString, names[i]);
```

and String's `format` method will substitute whatever is in `names[i]` for the `%s` in the format. There are also formats for ints, doubles, and dates.

For more info, see the Oracle Tutorial [on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [on manipulating Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the informative post! I'll definitely keep it in mind, although it doesn't seem to do what I originally wanted it to. Most likely a fault on my communication. Thanks, nevertheless! I'll keep the links in mind.

Comment: Yeah, you never mentioned iterating through the array as part of the problem you were having.

Comment: Yep, once more, it was just miscommunication on my part. Sorry to have you put you through all that trouble for naught! Have a nice day!